# CSS3 animating opacity in firefox on image

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, css-transitions, opacity

I have an image in a sticky navbar that I'd like to fade in when the navbar becomes fixed to the top of the page. Here's the html prior to applying the sticky class.

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <img width="115" height="30" id="logo" alt="Logo" src="navbar_logo.png">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#intro">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="blog/">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Once the navbar reaches the top of the page the only change is:

```
<nav class="navbar is-sticky" style="position: fixed; top: 0px;">...</nav>
```

The CSS that I'm using is:

```
#logo {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
}
.navbar #logo {
  margin: 5px 20px 0 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  opacity: 0;
}
.navbar.is-sticky  #logo {
  margin: 5px 20px 0 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

In Firefox the image simply appears, while in Chrome it fades in perfectly. I'm totally at a loss as to where the error is.

I've created a JSFiddle which recreates the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/Fnrr6/1/

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a bug, an older one that unfortunately didn't get enough attention:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=625289

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=788677

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=800927

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=821976

Changing the `position` to `fixed` or `absolute` kills the transition. As a workaround you could use a short timeout before adding the `is-sticky` class:

http://jsfiddle.net/fdRBH/

```
$('.navbar').css({
    position: 'fixed',
    top: 0
});
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.navbar').addClass('is-sticky');
},
60);
```